# Pyside setData flags on QStandardItem

Tags: python, pyside, qstandarditem

I have two questions here.

1. Where can I find a list of all the available flags/properties I can set using the setData method of a QstandardItem? I only know of the one below because i came across it online.
2. How do I set the Font of my QStandardItem to be bold?

**Python**

```
doors = QtGui.QStandardItem("Doors")

doors.setData(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 10, 255, 255)), role=QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)
```

Comment: Qt Documentation: (1) [ItemDataRole](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum), (2) [setFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#setFont).

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you. Would you be able to show or demonstrate how to do the bold font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Qt Documentation lists the [item data roles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum).
2. The font can be changed like this:

   ```
   font = item.font()
   font.setBold(True)
   item.setFont(font)
   ```

Comment: thank you. my approach was different than your solution so it was nice to see the various approaches.